# Can't ping to another linux machine by hostname

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, hostname, ping, hosts

When i try to ping to another linux machine in my local network i didn't work when i insert the host-name in the ping command.

```
sudo ping Raspberry2
```

It only works when i insert the IP address in the command

```
sudo ping 192.168.1.15
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Do you have an entry for Raspberry2 in `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: That is a possibility but because we do this in school we can't use a fixed IP address it changes every week

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

If you can't control the both the DHCP server and the name lookup service for your network, you're limited in what you can do. Typical options are /etc/hosts and a dynamic DNS service, but if you don't have root on either box then you'll just have to use the IP address directly.

### Resolving Names

You can't look up a host by name unless you are able to *resolve* it. The [Debian manual](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.hostname-name-service.html) explains:

> 8.3.1. Name Resolution
>   The mechanism for name resolution in Linux is modular and can use various sources of information declared in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file. The entry that involves host name resolution is hosts. By default, it contains `files dns`, which means that the system consults the /etc/hosts file first, then DNS servers. NIS/NIS+ or LDAP servers are other possible sources.

Since [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323924/cant-ping-to-another-linux-machine-by-hostname#comment569806_323924) says the target host has a dynamic IP address, if Raspberry2 doesn't update DNS (or one of the other data sources) when it gets its IP address, then you have to resolve it through a static entry in your /etc/hosts file or simply pass an IP address as you already do.

If your Raspberry Pi device is inside a private network, and if you can install the necessary software on it, a [dynamic DNS service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) may still help if the client supports looking up the IP assigned to the host's network interface, rather than just a publicly-resolvable IP address. Your mileage with dynamic DNS will most definitely vary.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the appropriate entry to your hosts file. Failing that, you will need to add the correct A record to your DNS.

Comment: This is a question, or two, not an answer.

Comment: Fair comment, I've edited the answer to be precise. I would have put it in a comment but I do not have the right yet. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

An A record shouldn't be required or host file entry if you are using public DNS you may find that you cannot see host names on the internal network however if you have not changed the DNS settings of your machine and either the router or internal dns server is either primary or secondary dns lookup server then you shouldn't run into this issue.

I would suggest checking your DNS settings and either a) adding host entry if you use public DNS or if you use your routers DNS make sure it allows local hostname resolving across the network

Answer (score 0):

It seems your DNS server isn't having record for Raspberry2. If you don't have DNS server, add the following line to your /etc/hosts file

192.168.1.15  Raspberry2